# StarUML do not display diagrams

Tags: uml, staruml

I am using the latest starUML BETA and I'm having these problems.
I have created 2 sequence diagrams and save it as a .mdj file.

After a few days, I wanted to continue working on the diagrams. But when I opened the file, the diagrams I was working on was not displayed. There is also nothing under the Working Diagrams area. But the Explorer section showed the items I have used in creating my diagrams.

I don't want to make my diagrams from scratch again. Is there a way that the diagrams will be displayed again?

Comment: Did you try [http://staruml.io/support](http://staruml.io/support)?

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same problem. Solved by **DOUBLE** clicking on Activity Diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To open the diagram, you should first click on the sequence diagram on the Explorer area on the right of the screen and then you'll see that your .mdj file is loaded.

As a reference: http://docs.staruml.io/en/latest/editing-elements-and-diagrams.html#open-diagram